# Google Apps Script Gadget fails to load App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have created a site using sites.coogle.com/a/ and written a google script which is listed under ManageSite-AppsScripts. The script draws data from a Google Docs spreadsheet to populate two listBoxes on a user form; which on submission, sends an email and logs the activity into another Google docs sheet. The script is authorized to run, and deployed as a web app, executing as "me" and allowing access to "Anyone, even anonymous". The app has been added to a web page  using Insert-AppsScriptGadget and selecting the App from the list of apps available on the site (only the one).

The app loads and runs correctly when I am logged in, but DOES NOT LOAD when a general user loads the web page. The stated error is "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

However, when I provide a normal hypertext link to the web app, such that it loads into a Google Chrome browser as a standalone html page, the app DOES LOAD and operate successfully for a general web user.

I would prefer to have the app appear as an Apps Scrip Gadget embedded in the page. Can anybody advise me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is wrong in you case. Could you have a look on instructions given [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_gadgets) to check if you have followed the steps correctly. If you still see issues, you may file it in [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry).

Also confirm, if you are using custom domain for your Google site. If so, Google Apps Script gadget will not work.

Comment: Thank you Waqar. I have re-examined the instructions which you suggested and believe that I have understood and satisfied the requirements. I shall make an entry in the issue tracker as you suggest.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2116&thanks=2116&ts=1353991063

Comment: It seems that this is a know and long time unresolved issue.[Issue 546: Google Apps Script Gadget not working with custom web address mapping](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=546)

Comment: Yes, I know that Apps Script Gadgets don't work with custom domains.

Comment: This issue has been partially resolved by Google :-) But, it is still not working for anonymous users. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=546